# MASM32 won't install correctly

Tags: assembly, installation, masm, masm32

I'm trying to install masm32 on my Windows 10 computer. I've tried the download from the masm website, http://www.masm32.com/ but whenever I try opening it, it only shows the border of the installer, and the inside is clear. Like this:
[image] Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: If you can start the `install.exe`the download was ok. Have you tried to run the `install.exe` as Administrator? Have you tried to run it in a compatibility mode?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both of those. Neither works.

Comment: I've tried it just now. No problems.

Comment: I've also restarted my computer recently, so that's not it.